# KL-Divergence on Uniform Distribution, is this correct?

Tags: uniform-distribution, kullback-leibler

$P_1$ is uniform on $[0, 0.5], ~P_2$ is uniform on  $ [0, 1] $

What is the KL-divergence $(P_1 \Vert P_2)?$

Attempt:

$$ D(p\Vert q) = \sum_{x\in X} p(x) \log \frac{p(x) }{q(x) }.$$

KL$(P_1\Vert P_2) =$ integral of $\log(1/2) =$  integral of $\log(1/2)$ from $0$ to $0.5 = \log(1/2)\times 0.5 . $

KL$(P_2\Vert P_1) =$ KL$(P_1\Vert P_2)$

Comment: The support of the two Uniform distributions doesn't coincide in the manner of absolute continuity between the measure $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$. Then only KL divergence that can be calculated is $KL(P_{1}||P_{2}).$ The $KL(P_{2}||P_{1})$ cannot be calculated since there is a set $(0.5,1]$ for which the $P_{2}$ is non zero but the $P_{1}$ is.

Comment: Is the KL transitive? KL(A||B) = KL(B || A)

Comment: I think what you are looking for is if the KL is symmetric distance

Comment: I see, I am trying to calculate KL-Divergence. Is my calculation correct?

Comment: I think what you must calculate is $\int_{[0,0.5]}\frac{1}{0.5-0}log\frac{\frac{1}{0.5-0}}{1}dx = \int_{[0,0.5]}2log(2)dx=log(2)$

Comment: So this is log(2) as the answer.

Comment: I see, and the other way KL(P2 || P1) is non-tractable because of division by 0, is this correct?

Comment: if you answer is equal to $log(2)$ then I think it is correct

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: @Fiodor1234: That looks like you have an answer, can you write it up, that is, in the answer box?